# entity data model not available in database data source configuration for winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, datasource

Using VS2015.  New WinForms App.  New EF 6.1.3 DB model installed and compiled.  I have verified the EF model is good through C# code use.

When I go to select my Entity DataSource this is the window I get when I select Database:

[image: VS2015 Data Source Configuration Wizard]

According to all of the instructions from Microsoft and others, I should see an Entity Data Model option here.  However, I do not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you installed the SQLServerTools in VS setup which also includes EF support?

Comment: Yes.  And performed the obligatory reboot just to be safe.